# Change checkbox color by dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down html code. I need to target a click event on the drop-down, if some-value pressed some checkboxes's color should change.

```
 <select>
        <option value="calculate">calculate</option>
        <option value="identification">identification</option>
        <option value="longInputs">longInputs</option>
</select>
```

I want to know how can I target a click event on the value in the drop-down.
An example : if someone clicked on the identification row than some checkboxes would change to red.

I have searched all the way and couldn't find how to do it. Hope to get a little help

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery here would be your friend, you can use the change event

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Comment: I have treid to put for my select tag a target class but nothing happend. Where should I modify the code?

Comment: you can see examples of how to use this on jquery's site http://api.jquery.com/change/